# comparing command output with string returns 'command not found'

Tags: bash, operators

I have a program that triggers a script. The script works when I run it manually, but for some reason I get an error when the program runs it. It is supposed to trigger another command if the curl command returns `true` after parsing some JSON. Here is the relevant portion:

`if 
  $(curl -s -b cookie  "https://my.site.com/api" | /config/jq --arg var "test" '.Items[] | .item1[] | select( .Name== $var ) | .Valid') = "true"
then`

It returns `=: command not found`. I tried removing the whitespaces from the `=` and it returns `=true: command not found`. I tried putting brackets around it like this:

`if 
  [ $(curl -s -b cookie  "https://my.site.com/api" | /config/jq --arg var "test" '.Items[] | .item1[] | select( .Name== $var ) | .Valid') = "true" ]
then`

But that gives me an error related to the brackets. I have `#!/bin/bash` set at the beginning of the script and made sure there are no carriage return issues. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using `[[` and `== "true"`

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to fix it. I need to get more familiar with my operators.

Comment: Any idea why it works in the terminal but not the other way?